# Can I pass array using WCF DataMember

Tags: wcf

Assume my WCF interface declared like that:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IManagementConsole
{
    [OperationContract]
    ConsoleData GetData(int strategyId);

[DataContract]
public class ConsoleData
{
    .....
    [DataMember]
    public int[] GetConnectionsStats { get; set; }
}
```

In my program I just assign value:

```
....
ConsoleData data = new ConsoleData();
....
data.GetConnectionsStats = Program.GetConnectionsStats();
```

The question is - will that work? Array is actually a pointer? I guess probably pointer will be passed over WCF instead of passing array data?

Comment: WCF serializes all messages into XML format for transmission - so your arrays will be converted into arrays in an XML document, basically. There's no pointers or links back to the other side of the communication in WCF (it's **not** a remote procedure call mechanism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing preventing you from passing an array from the client to the server and from the server to the client. Remember that before the actual sending and receiving occurs, data is serialized in order to be transported over the wire. So, no pointers. The data is serialized at the sender's side and deserialized back on the receiver's side.

In the example you have shown, there is a service operation which returns an object containing an array of integers. When the client invokes the GetData method, the server will serialize the `ConsoleData` contract using the configured binding and send it over the wire.

On the client side, a copy of this data will be reconstructed by deserializing what is received.

Comment: so WCF can serialize array of int for me? can it serialize array of Object?

Comment: @javapowered, yes WCF will serialize an array of int for you. As far as an array of object is concerned, it will also do it, but you will have to indicate the known types (a.k.a. all the possible types that this server can return): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WCF doesn't pass the array pointer. It provides the ability to create a service which you consume from an application and it exchanges messages through the underlying exposing of methods which use Xml payloads to transfer data via deserialization etc.

What will happen is you would implement a service that implements your `IManagementInterface` Which in turn would implement your `GetData` Method.

This returns you your `ConsoleData` object for you to use and would contain the property `GetConnectionStats` which would have the data you would set during your `GetData` method.

So in short. The array you initialise in your service, is transferred as data to your application where it is then deserialized back into its format for you to use.